# Complex number calculations given values for z1 and z2

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the question:

> Given that $z_1 = 4 - 3i$  and $z_2 = -3 + 4i$, determine:
>   a) $2z_1 - z_2$
>   b) $z_1z_2$
>   c) $z_1\overline{z_1}$

Here is my attempt. Is it correct?

**a)**
$$\begin{align}2z_1 - z_2&=2(4-3i)-(-3+4i)\\&=8-6i+3-4i\\&=8+3-6i-4i\\&=11-10i\end{align}$$

**b)**
$$\begin{align}z_1z_2&=(4-3i)(-3+4i)\\&=-12+16i+9i-12i^2\\&=-12+16i+9i-12(-1)\\&=-12+16i+9i+12\\&=16+9i\\&=25i\end{align}$$

**c)**
$$\begin{align}z_1\overline{z_1}&=(4-3i)(4+3i)\\&=16+12i-12i-9i^2\\&=16-9(-1)\\&=16-(-9)\\&=25\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, these are correct.

Comment: Okay thanks just making sure :)

Comment: You can always check your solution [here](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/7/KUMFWwURBV8FYwdOaq8oIyNM1VtAGCgG5XAFFmXkl0UYKQFW6ClVGsVABIFcLneucn5dVmp5Ykgrkxsb@/w8A).

Comment: Wow thanks that's pretty cool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 1 year on MSE why not start typing in Latex?

It is not that much complicated or different from normal writing for basic stuff like indices `z_1`=$z_1$, exponents `i^2`=$i^2$,`z^*`=$z^*$ and `\\`=line break.

You can go for advanced stuff as you go along with the site.

Look for instance at a transcription of $(a)$.

$2z_1-z_2\\
=2(4-3i)-(-3+4i)\\
=8-6i+3-4i\\
=8+3-6i-4i\\
=11-10i$

```
$2z_1-z_2\\
=2(4-3i)-(-3+4i)\\
=8-6i+3-4i\\
=8+3-6i-4i\\
=11-10i$
```

Anyway, notice that for $z=x+iy$ then $$zz^*=x^2+y^2$$

You can use this shortcut instead of doing $\require{cancel}(x+iy)(x-iy)=x^2-\cancel{ixy}+\cancel{ixy}-i^2y^2=x^2-(-1)y^2=x^2+y^2$.

So $z_1z_1^*=4^2+3^2=16+9=25$.

And remark that $z_2=4i-3=i(4+3i)=i(4-3i)^*=iz_1^*$

So $z_1z_2=i(z_1z_1^*)=i(25)=25i$

Comment: Thanks I really wanted to know how to do that :)